# How to work with Aggregate function in LINQ with join

Tags: linq

Need help in LINQ expression,
I have 2 tables `Article` and `comments` foreign key is `Article_id` .Now i need data using both the tables using linq to sql like `article_id,Article_title,Total_Comments`(Count of comments on current article article),

tale Structure :

```
table 1(Article) : Article_ID,Article_Title.. etc
table 2(comments ): Comment_auto_id,Comment_text,Comment_by(User_ID),Article_ID
```

Comment: Doesn't `Article` have a navigation property `Comments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that ?

```
from article in Articles
join comment in Comments on article.Article_ID equals comment.ArticleID into articleComments
select new {
  Article = article,//or more detailed if you want only part of Articles entity
  Total_Comments = articleComments.Count()
}
```

Comment: thanx dear will have "equals" instead of "=" .This is what i want.I was waisting my time on grouping :( thank you very much. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use .GroupJoin() extension method.
Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin.aspx